# Does objective C support the caldav?

Tags: objective-c, caldav

I want to ask a question about the objective C. Do the objective C and iOS 4 support the caldav? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objective-C is just the programming language. So itself it does not support this kind of stuff. Cocoa Touch is the framework that could support such a thing. But it doesn't. The only thing you can is access calendars from the calendar app. But there is no support to directly deal with CalDAV. But you could for e.g. use a third party lib like libical (http://sourceforge.net/projects/freeassociation/)